# Display number of record entries by user

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have a visualforce page that displays user contribution by CreatedById. Here is my controller code:

```
public List<AggregateResult> getTop6Contributors()
{
    return [
        SELECT CreatedById, CreatedBy.Name Name
        FROM Idea
        GROUP BY CreatedById, CreatedBy.Name
        ORDER BY count(CreatedById) desc limit 6
    ];
}
```

How do I display on my page the number of records a user has submitted?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean to alias `CreatedBy.Name` as `Name` or were you trying to query `Name` as well?

Comment: It was an alias. I don't have a Name field in my Idea sObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would lazy load that property since it probably will not change in the context of the page. Just add (and name) what you want to query.

```
public List<AggregateResult> top6Contributors
{
    get
    {
        if (top6Contributors == null)
        {
            top6Contributors = [
                SELECT CreatedById, CreatedBy.Name name,
                    count(Id) contributions
                FROM Idea
                GROUP BY CreatedById, CreatedBy.Name
                ORDER BY count(CreatedById) desc limit 6
            ];
        }
        return top6Contributors;
    }
    private set;
}
```

And on your page something like:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!top6Contributors}" value="contributor">
    <apex:outputText value="{!contributor.contributions}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: I get the following error: "expecting a semi-colon, found '}' at line 26 column 4". This is where the curly bracket before "private set;" is. Any ideas?

Comment: It was missing after the `return` in the getter.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Now I am getting this error: "Grouped field should not be aggregated: CreatedById" after the SELECT command.

Comment: Try passing `Id` to the count function instead.